# Como limito uma caixa de texto?

Tags: html

Preciso colocar um limite de linhas em uma caixa de texto, e também usar um `trasition` para que quando a pessoa *click* no texto ele abra e mostre toda a mensagem.
Se alguem tiver alguma ideia Agradeço XD

Comment: O que você quer dizer com limitar linhas? você se refere a quebra de linha inserida pelo usuário? ou a que é feita automaticamente quando atinge a borda do textarea?

Answer (score 2):

Segue exemplo onde o tamanho do campo vai aumentar caso o texto seja maior que o tamanho inicial definido.

Clique coloque um texto, clique fora e clique no input novamente para testar!

```js
$( "#texto" ).click(function() {
  var tamanhoTexto = $(this).val().length;
  if (tamanhoTexto > 2){
     console.log(tamanhoTexto);
     $(this).attr('size',tamanhoTexto);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="texto" type="text"  maxlength="20" size="2"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo, ela tem a altura de `1rem` ou seja, 100% da altura da font padrão. E quando vc foca nela ela fica com altura de `3em`, ou seja 3x a altura da font do elemento pai. Isso deixa o tamanho um pouco mais responsivo.

Usei o `required` para fazer as regras de estilos no CSS, assim se o campo não estiver preenchido ele sempre fica no tamanho original. Também coloque `resize:none;` para não deixar o usuário aumentar o tamanho do box

A animação vc pode fazer com `transition` como no exemplo abaixo:

```css
textarea {
    width: 300px;
    height: 1rem;
    resize: none;
    transition: height 700ms;
}
textarea:focus, textarea:valid  {
    height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <textarea required></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando os atributos do `<textarea>`:

```
<textarea name="textarea" cols="10" rows="10" wrap="textarea">
```

cols -> número de colunas

rows -> número de linhas

wrap -> quebra de texto

> [Referência do **textarea**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Eu prefiro separar as responsabilidades para evitar command-inline. Acho melhor você também se acostumar dessa forma, mas as duas formas acima não estão erradas.

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Tente usar o campo como:

```
textarea {
    width: 300px;
    height: 1rem;
    resize: none;
    transition: height 700ms;
}
textarea:focus, textarea:valid  {
    height: 3em;
}
```